# Modify Ilist for a Web Drop-down list without NHibernate persisting changes

Tags: nhibernate

I'd like to use NHibernate to populate an IList, which will be used to populate an HTML SELECT element.  I want to insert an element as the first element that will say, "Please select an item".  However, will NHibernate persist the new element to the database when session.Flush() is called?  If yes, then is there a way to avoid persisting the new element to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you do with NHibernate is retrieve a list of objects using a query, then nothing will be persisted.

If you add elements to a persistent collection, changes will be persisted.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there any way to modify the list without persisting it?

Comment: Just copy the elements to a different list and use *that* for databinding.

Comment: Good idea. We decided to add the "Please select an item" list value in the HTML.